# Conversion of 2000x3 decimal matrix .txt file into binary 2000x3 .txt file

Tags: matlab, binary, decimal

To begin, I have 2000x3 matrix .txt file that contains decimal numbers within, so I want to convert all decimal values to binary representation of them. How can I do that in Matlab? Thanks in advance!
e.g

```
6   6   13
2   6   46
4   5   10
20  30  70
10  24  182
80  44  446
19  13  940
18  9   15
60  33  16
4   28  220
2   6   46
30  26  53
16  8   98
10  24  250
18  20  512
....
.....
```

Comment: What do you mean with “binary representation”? Could you include what the output should look like?

Comment: I tried to say Binary Coded Decimal (BCD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume the following:

- All the numbers in the matrix are `int`s and that you want to store them in binary as 8-byte `int`s in little-endian format.
- You want the data file to be contiguous in each row: i.e. 6 is followed by 6 then 13 then 2 ...

With these assumptions, here is one way to accomplish the goal:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt', 'r');
A = fscanf(fid, '%d', [3, 2000])'; % now A is a 2000x3 matrix that looks like your sample
fclose(fid);

% do stuff with A, if desired

fid = fopen('myfile.dat', 'w');
fwrite(fid, A', 'int', 'l'); % note the transpose
fclose(fid);
```

The transpose in `fwrite` is because MATLAB uses column-major indexing whereas the code assumes the output should be row-major indexed.

Comment: This really helped!